# XSLT: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring-after()

Tags: xml, xslt

From the XML below, I'm trying to get the value of `Value1` under the tag `Agt`

I'm getting below error. Please advise

**Error:**

A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring-after() ("File: 13523523362353000270", "File: 13590585000270")

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:test1">
   <File>
      <Header>
         <ID>107851</ID>
      </Header>
      <Detail>
         <Seg>           
            <Agt>442REFP20210804</Agt>
            <Amt>
               <Value>
                  <Value1>File: 13523523362353000270</Value1>
               </Value>
            </Amt>
         </Seg>
          <Seg>           
              <Agt>EFP20210841504</Agt>
              <Amt>
                  <Value>
                      <Value1>File: 13590585000270</Value1>
                  </Value>
              </Amt>
          </Seg>            
      </Detail>
   </File>
</Document>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:cc1="urn:test1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="cc1" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- To copy the entire xml -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/cc1:Document/cc1:File/cc1:Detail/cc1:Seg/cc1:Agt">
        <xsl:element namespace="urn:test1"
            name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(../../cc1:Seg/cc1:Amt/cc1:Value/cc1:Value1,'File: ')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:test1">
   <File>
      <Header>
         <ID>107851</ID>
      </Header>
      <Detail>
         <Seg>
            <Agt>13523523362353000270</Agt>
            <Amt>
               <Value>
                  <Value1>File: 13523523362353000270</Value1>
               </Value>
            </Amt>
         </Seg>
         <Seg>
            <Agt>13590585000270</Agt>
            <Amt>
               <Value>
                  <Value1>File: 13590585000270</Value1>
               </Value>
            </Amt>
         </Seg>
      </Detail>
   </File>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess instead of `substring-after(../../cc1:Seg/cc1:Amt` you want `substring-after(../cc1:Amt`.